# C# List to Dictionary without Foreach [ERROR]

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, lambda

I have this class

```
class Person
{
    public string idCard { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
}
```

and a list of objects

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>(){
    new Person(){name="John",idCard="123",birthDate=new DateTime(1990,11,13)},
    new Person(){name="Paul",idCard="321",birthDate=new DateTime(1988,5,16)},
    new Person(){name="Clara",idCard="213",birthDate=new DateTime(1993,7,21)}
};
```

When I want to convert that list into dictionary without foreach, where one of the object's attributes is the key (I have searched all the way to do that in the web)

```
Dictionary<string, Person> personDict = new Dictionary<string,Person>();
personDict = list.GroupBy(x=>x.idCard).ToDictionary<string, Person>(x => x.Key,x=>x);
```

I still  got some errors

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'   G:\SHUBA\Learning\Experiments\TestProgram\TestProgram\Program.cs    25  26  TestProgram
>   Error   4   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'   G:\SHUBA\Learning\Experiments\TestProgram\TestProgram\Program.cs    25  95  TestProgram
>   Error   3   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func' G:\SHUBA\Learning\Experiments\TestProgram\TestProgram\Program.cs    25  83  TestProgram
>   Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid arguments   G:\SHUBA\Learning\Experiments\TestProgram\TestProgram\Program.cs    25  26  TestProgram

Does anyone know the solution?

I think I have it right.

Comment: I just think linq or lambda performs better. If I have 10.000.000 objects I'm sure it slows the process.

Comment: DId you try, do not assume but measure.

Comment: If you try to measure the performance of the ToDictionary solution and a simple foreach you will discover that a foreach is constantly more faster.

Comment: I have just tried it, for 10.000.000 data, ToDictionary needs 3.021174s, while foreach consumes 4.1892389s

Comment: Of course I couldn't try when I don't know why I was wrong. I tried after I got solutions in the below answers section. Thanks for everyone who answers my question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a dictionary where the key is the `idCard` and value is the `Person` object.

```
Dictionary<string, Person> personDict = list.ToDictionary(x => x.idCard, y => y);
```

Since we are going to make the `IdCard` value as the dictionary key, The [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) method call will throw an `ArgumentException` if your list has more than one item with same `idCard` value.

Answer (score 3):

The grouping is not necessary, `ToDictionary` does it for you. This should be simple as:

```
var personDict = list.ToDictionary(p => p.idCard);
```

Btw. there is no need to declare variable personDict and assign it to empty dictionary in first step & reassign it one line later.

Comment: Oh my... It's so embarrassing. I think I've done too much. Anyway thank you very much